# How to plot a function with argument as degree

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pst-plot

I want to plot a function. The function is, F is proportional to x/cos(x). Here x is rotation in degree and F is the force. I have to plot the graph where the x axis will be from 0 to 70 degree and the y axis will be linear value 0 to 5.

I am not able to find any option to draw graphs where x axis is with rotational degree.

I was using these codes:

```
\begin{document} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
grid=both, 
trig format plots=deg 
domain=0:70, samples=50, no marks, 
xticklabels={0$\deg$,10$\deg$,20$\deg$,30$\deg$,40$\deg$,50$\deg$,60$\deg$,70$\deg$}, 
xtick={deg(0),deg(10),deg(20),deg(30),deg(40),deg(50),deg(60),deg(70)}, x post scale = 5 ] \addplot {deg(x)/cos(deg(x))}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Edit the question you already asked and include compilable code.

Comment: So you asked a question, you got answers (in comment) then you ask it again in another thread? Please, refrain from doing this as it only pollutes this website. And you can delete your previous question, since you got answer here. And maybe read a bit about how to use this website correctly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the next result:

[image]

It is produced by:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=both,
trig format plots=deg,
xtick={0,10,...,70},
xticklabels={\SI{0}{\degree},\SI{10}{\degree},\SI{20}{\degree},\SI{30}{\degree},%
                             \SI{40}{\degree},\SI{50}{\degree},\SI{60}{\degree},%
                             \SI{70}{\degree}},
domain=0:70, samples=70, no marks,
            ]
\addplot {cos(x)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note:

- you had to provide MWE (similar as is done in this answer), a small but complete document, which produce your problem
- your code fragment contain errors

Comment: This works.Thanks a lot.